# MFC like easy to use tool for Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

When I used to write test tools in Windows, I use MFC for creating the front-end GUI. This made development of GUI development very fast, and I always used to concentrate on the back-end. Recently I moved to the console based Linux-world. Where most of the things are just console based.

My question: Is there any easy to use equivalent of MFC in Linux?

Comment: How can it be easy to use if its like MFC? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used MFC, but supposedly the wxWidgets toolkit is somewhat MFC-like. Though I prefer Qt over wxWidgets as IMHO the API is nicer, more complete and better documented, and the Qt GUI builder is pretty good.

A nice thing with both Qt and wxWidgets BTW is that they are both cross-platform toolkits; they work on Linux/Unix, Windows, OS X, and maybe other platforms as well.

Answer (score 10):

If you are used to MFC, you will LOVE QT.

http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of alternatives.

I like wxWidgets.  Others will recommend Qt.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) to build [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) or [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/) applications.

Comment: If he's used to MFC, Glade/GTK+/GNOME are a pretty far cry from it.

Comment: Since the question was about C++, I'm baffled by why you didn't mention GTKmm. All the power and market reach of GTK+ - with all the OOP and just-plain-readability of C++. Criminally unknown/underrated imho.

Answer (score 0):

There's a a huge omission here! **[gtkmm](http://gtkmm.org/)**, the official C++ binding to GTK+, is arguably *the* modern C++ GUI kit, since it goes out of its way to really use and evolve with the language. For those learning modern C++, it's the best counterpart to the stdlib. It grabbed and kept my interest, where no other GUI lib could, due to its modern and clear API. And it'll work wherever GTK+ does - a *tonne* of places. I'm glad to have built my first ever (and not trivial!) GUI project around it. It also provides *sigc++*, which I imagine is really powerful for custom signalling/event systems. Disclaimer: I'm just a self-taught user.